# "present perfect" vs "past perfect"

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-perfect

Should I use **present perfect** or **past perfect** in the following context? Are they both correct?

- Jason, did you see yesterday's match between Liverpool and Chelsea? What a match it was! I **have never/had never seen** a match like that before.

I think both are correct but I am not sure. I think If I use **past perfect** it mean "before yesterday's match" and If I use **present perfect** it brings my experience to the present day.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Either is grammatically correct, but in the context "I have never seen a match like that before" is a better fit for something which happened recently, and which is being discussed in the present.